# SettingWithCopyWarning in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've searched quite a bit and read the documentation but I'm still not sure why I'm getting this warning. I am referencing the DataFrame by column and only at a single level. I'm not setting anything in this code.

Here's the error:

```
afr.py:51: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  list_deciles.append(iter_summary(df[df['decile'] == s]))
```

Here's the code snippet:

```
def qcut_variable(df, variable):
    df['decile']=pd.qcut(df[variable],10)
    df_group_by = df.groupby('decile')
    list_deciles = []
    for s in df['decile'].cat.categories:
        list_deciles.append(iter_summary(df[df['decile'] == s]))
    df_deciles = pd.DataFrame(list_deciles)
    return df_deciles
```

Comment: What's `iter_summary`, it's unclear where this is raising but I don't think the `df[df['decile'] == s]` doing any setting?

Comment: iter_summary is a function that returns a Series (it's a long function with dependencies so I didn't post it here). That's why I'm confused -- because nothing that I can see is doing any setting. If it was something in iter_summary, wouldn't the warning be raised from the line in iter_summary?

Comment: if you're using ipython then you can use %debug.